# IOS Parallax and page view like Android ParallaxHeaderViewPager

Tags: ios, android-viewpager, parallax

I want to try like this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCP-b0a1x5Y. I need Parallax efect and view pager.
 Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Do have check at this library it seems to be answering your question and others who have similar requirements... It supports parallax view with pagercontrol like android for iOS.
Here's [a link](https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager)!